# Standard idiom for executing a while loop one more time

Tags: c, while-loop, idioms

Is there a pattern in C to execute a while loop one more time.
Currently I'm using

```
while(condition) {
    condition = process();
    // process() could be multiple lines instead of a function call
    // so while(process());process(); is not an option
}
process();
```

which is horrible if process is of multiple lines and not a single function call.

The alternative is

```
bool run_once_more = 1;
while(condition || run_once_more) {
    if (!condition) {
        run_once_more = 0;
    }
    condition = process();
    condition = condition && run_once_more;
}
```

Is there a better way?

---

Note: A do while loop is not a solution as it is equivalent to

```
process();
while(condition){condition=process();}
```

I want

```
while(condition){condition=process();}
process();
```

---

Per requests, a bit more specific code.
I want to fill buffer from another_buffer and get 
(indexof(next_set_bit) + 1) into MSB while maintaining both masks and pointers.

```
uint16t buffer;
...
while((buffer & (1 << (8*sizeof(buffer) - 1))) == 0) { // get msb as 1
    buffer <<= 1;
    // fill LSB from another buffer
    buffer |= (uint16_t) (other_buffer[i] & other_buffer_mask);
    // maintain other_buffer pointers and masks
    other_buffer_mask >>= 1;
    if(!(other_buffer_mask)) { 
        other_buffer_mask = (1 << 8*sizeof(other_buffer[0]) -1)
        ++i;
    }
}
// Throw away the set MSB
buffer <<= 1;
buffer |= (uint16_t) (other_buffer[i] & other_buffer_mask);
other_buffer_mask >>= 1;
if(!(other_buffer_mask)) { 
    other_buffer_mask = (1 << 8*sizeof(other_buffer[0]) -1)
    ++i;
}
use_this_buffer(buffer);
```

Comment: `process is of multiple lines and not a single function call` Then make it (possibly inline) function call.

Comment: A `do ... while (condition);` can also provide an additional iteration in some cases.

Comment: @chux It would be ok if condition was modified in the last call as well. Still, the do while loop would ***NOT*** make an additional iteration ***after*** the condition is false. see my note.

Comment: Can you tell use more about `condition`? Is it something numeric or what?

Comment: @black added more info.

Comment: BTW, rather than `1 << (8*sizeof(buffer) - 1)`, use `1u << (8*sizeof buffer - 1)`  (add u).  or even better `1u << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof buffer - 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not a very typical thing to do, it's unlikely that there is a standard idiom for doing this.  However, I'd write the code like this:

```
for (bool last = 0; condition || last; last = !(condition || last)) {
    condition = process();
}
```

The loop will execute as long as `condition` is true and then one more time, or zero times if `condition` is false when the loop begins.  I interpret your question as meaning that that is the desired behavior.  If not, and you always want the loop to execute at least once, then `do...while` is the idiom you seek.

Comment: ++0, This feels like the most elegant solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
int done, condition = 1;
for (;;) {
    ...
    done = !condition;
    condition = process();
    if (done) break;
    ...
}
```

I am not suggesting this is a standard idiom, just an ad hoc hack.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
bool done = false;
do {
  if (!condition) done = true;
  condition = process();
} while (!done);
```

A much less readable hack, assuming `condition` is not predefined:

```
for (bool condition=true, done=false;
     !done && (condition || done = true);
    ) {
  condition = process();
}
```

Comment: `condition` must be defined as something non 0 and there is a missing semicolon after the end of the `do/while` condition.

Comment: @chqrlie: In the OP, `condition` is pre-existing. I assumed it came from some previous computation. If that is not the case, then it would have to defined, yes.

Answer (score 0):

### I've had this same issue and my solution is:

Only if you know for sure you want to run process() at least once:

```
while(1){
    process();
    if(!condition()) break;
    /*The loop breaks before bad things happen*/
    things_you_want_to_happen_only_while_condition_is_true();
}
```

If you are not sure:

```
if(condition()){ /*Same as before, but it checks first*/
    while(1){
        process();
        if(!condition()) break;
        /*The loop breaks before bad things happen*/
        things_you_want_to_happen_only_while_condition_is_true();
    }
}
```

For example:

```
/*A pointer that goes over the string T from right to left.
It prints "Yes" when pointing at the character 'O' and "No" when not*/
char T[] = {'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W', 0};
char *P = &T[strlen(T)-1]; /*We want the pointer to start at the last character of T*/
while(1){
    if(*P=='O') printf("Yes\n");
    else printf("No\n");
    if(P==&T[0]) break; /*When it reaches the beginning of T, it stops*/
    /*We only want the pointer to go further back if it is not in the beginning of T.
    That's because we don't know what's before in the memory.*/
    P--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way more advanced than my level, but I came to this question as I had a similar difficulty on a problem set (I wanted the function to execute one last time) and I solved it like this:

```
define check_value as type_required;

while (check_value)
{
    check_value = additional_output_from_process;
    condition = process();
}
```

Would something like that work? In my problem I'm just taking a modulus so I can just run the process twice, system overhead really isn't a consideration.

This works in my example but it might just be a specific use case? I don't know, I'm literally only 6 months into coding.

I think what I'm trying to say is: introduce an additional value, and set the logical test so that the `function output (operation) additional value = true`. Then set the value of the additional value before you evalutate the function. The result `function output (operation) additional value` then will only be set to true after the loop has already run again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this solves OP's problem. OP wants the loop to continue until `process()` returns false then execute `process()` one more time

Comment: I get that - I'm trying to not post part of a homework answer online so that it's really obvious.