# Read a file line by line in php without repeating batching code

Tags: php

How do I read a file line by line in php without repeating batching code?

I'm sure I must be having a brain freeze and this must be simple.

```
# Record batch if needed
if ( count($addresses) == $limit or (count($addresses) and feof($fh)) ) {
        $success = record($addresses);
        if ( ! $success ) break;
        $addresses=[];
}
```

That `or (count($addresses) and feof($fh))` condition doesn't work because php requires another fgets() call for $fh to find EOF.

I tried using fseek to seek ahead but it wasn't working easily.

In the past, I've just repeated the record() function after the loop but it's really bugging me that I have to do that.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean when you say "batching code"

Comment: Is there a reason why something like this doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/231316 And inside of the `while` loop you could do you `count` test maybe, and just `break` if needed

Comment: Why not https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Batching code is like accumulating data over multiple iterations and then processing it only say once every 10 iterations

Comment: @AbraCadaver Batching is a technique that implies the coder necessarily can't just read in an entire file

Comment: Sorry, when you said "repeating batching code", that's where I had confusion, because I didn't understand what you were repeating.

Comment: The reading shouldn't be dependent on the recording. Chris's link should be sufficient for the reading of the file. Inside the read loop, build up your array that you want to record, and then check the count of the array to see if you want to record and empty it or continue on. Add another record line after the file has been completely read.

Comment: @aynber Yes, that's how it works, but it requires another record() after the file read loop to record the remaining items that weren't caught inside the loop because the accumulating array hadn't reached the limit yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by the last line of that comment. That's probably the best way to go about it. At least, I haven't noticed any other way to do it with all of my file import batching scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? It is just an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/231316), and every `10` lines we process the batch, and we process one last time at the end of the loop.

```php
function processBatch(array $batch)
{
    // Do work here
}

if (!$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r")) {
    die("File not found");
}

$batch = [];
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $batch[] = $line;
    if (count($batch) === 10) {
        processBatch($batch);
        $batch = [];
    }
}

processBatch($batch);

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Yes, repeating processBatch() is what I'd like to avoid repeating. Sounds funny when I write it down :)

Comment: I think this is a pretty common pattern in programming, and I could understand it feeling weird at first glance. There's even a question about it here, and if you look at some of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477636/231316), I personally think readability goes down, whereas a simple comment of `// Run one last time in case anything is left in the buffer` is very easy to read

Comment: I'm just surprised there isn't a builtin function to be used inside the loop to determine eof without having to read more data...or alternatively a builtin that does it all for you (ie. seek ahead 1 byte, check eof, rewind 1 byte). I tried doing this myself quickly but fseek() wasn't working for me.

Comment: I _think_ the answer is that it would be inefficient. Your code would effectively become "read stuff, read next byte, rewind one byte", and the pointer would always have to be shuffled forth and back on every read (by virtue of you calling the proposed function). Another possible answer is just that not all streams support seeking, and the `f*` functions are meant to work on all streams.